# Strip Chinese Characters from a string (vba)

Tags: regex, vba, ms-office

I am using Microsoft Project VBA to translate my activity names from English to Chinese.

My problem is I have some Chinese translations embedded in some of the English activity names. I want to strip out the Chinese characters before passing the string to Microsoft Translator.

Any ideas as to how I can do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `Regexp` to strip the Chinese unicode characters

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs) lists the relevant characters below

[image]

```
Sub Test()
Dim myString as String
myString = "This is my string with a " & ChrW$(&H6C49) & " in it."
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u6300-\u77FF\u7800-\u8CFF\u8D00-\u9FFF]+"
    MsgBox .Replace(myString, vbNullString)
End With
End Sub
```

So this regexp will strip out these ranges. I have used *aldo.roman.nurena's* string example

Comment: Why not simply .Pattern = "[\u4E00-\u9FFF]+" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ChrW$()` as this:

```
MyString = "This is my string with a " & ChrW$(&H6C49) & " in it."
```

The `H6C49` is available (thanks God for that) on Unicode as CJK codes (Chinese, Japanese and Korean). See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs) to take a look of the characters range.

So, you have to check the character Unicode code and then compare if it is already on the CJK range so as to translate it or not.

There is also a good explanation and even a program to translate strings [here](http://teaandbiscuits.org.uk/drupal/node/77)