# Detecting text language in LibreOffice calc

Tags: multilingual, libreoffice-calc

I want to automate text language detection in LibreOffice Calc.

I have only 4 languages, each language has its own character set.
Languages are **not** or **rarely** mixed in cells.

Languages are: English, Hebrew, Arabic, Russian.

As depicted in the picture bellow:
[image]

I want to write a formula in column `C` cell, that will indicate the text language in the corresponding `A` cell.

I failed to identify any style indicator I can use.

I looked around and found a solution for [Microsoft Office VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369353/detect-text-language-in-vba).

I hope I do not need to write a macro using this [API function](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1i18n_1_1XCharacterClassification.html#a410c11924866da1e09f12534b96a1ade) `getStringType(...)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the text in a given cell is using the same script and that all text starts with a letter, testing the first character should be enough. This can be done with:

```
=UNICODE(A2)
```

If the number returned is between 65 and 122, the text is in English (this would need to be extended if you need to include characters with diacritical marks (ex.: é, à, ñ, ø, etc.)

The same can be done with the other alphabets. A Unicode character list can be used to determine the range in question. [Here is one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin_Extended-A) though you can easily find others that may better suit your purpose